# Getting offset of STRUC member in assembly

Tags: assembly, tasm

So, I have such structure:

```
String STRUC
   max_length       db  254
   real_length      db  ?
   buffer           db  255  dup(?)
String ENDS
```

In data segment I define variable of my «String» type:

```
source_str          String <>
```

And in code segment I'm trying to get the offset of structure member «buffer»:

```
mov     bx, offset source_str           ; in BX we have the offset of structure
lea     dx, [bx].buffer                 ; OK, the right offset in DX
mov     ax, offset [source_str].buffer  ; this works fine too
mov     dx, offset [bx].buffer          ; but this gets _wrong_ offset, according to td
```

I'm beginner and this is the way I think: we have an offset (in register or as label) - address, place it between [] and get the value - it's like pointer dereferencing in C/C++.

And my question is: why the last command doesn't work as I think it should? Is there a way to do this using "mov" and offset in BX register?

Comment: Since you apparently want the actual address and not the offset within the structure, you need to add `bx` and `mov` can't do that. You need `lea` as you showed.

Comment: @Jester I get not the offset within the structure, but totally wrong value. For example: offset of «buffer» is 0003, offset within the structure is 2 bytes, but I get 6558.

Comment: @nyagod - what is the offset of source_str? I'm wondering if it's 6556?

Answer (score 3):

For masm 6.11 the struc name needs to be included:

```
        lea     dx, (String ptr [bx]).buffer
```

For the other problem, you can't use offset with a base register:

```
        mov     dx, offset (String ptr [bx]).buffer  ; invalid
```

You could use add, but lea does the same thing with one instruction:

```
        mov     dx, bx
        add     dx, offset (String ptr ds:0).buffer
```